# Уведомления при добавлении новой записи на сайт на WordPress

Tags: android, wordpress

Написал клиент для сайта на WordPress используя `Retrofit2`. Есть ссылка http://udeveloper.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?category=9, которая возвращает json и с помощью retrofit данные выводятся в `RecyclerView`, а при нажатии на пункт списка открывается активность с полной статьей.

Вопрос в следующем: как реализовать в моем приложении вывод уведомления, когда на сайт в частности в данную рубрику добавляется новая запись?

Как создать само уведомление я знаю. А вот как приложение может понять что новая запись была опубликована и уведомить об этом пользователя?

В моем понимании должен быть сервис, который проверяет появление новых записей.

Как обычно такое реализовывают?

Comment: стандартные push notifications.

Comment: ну а как понять вообще что запись новая появилась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте плагин [Push Notifications for WordPress (Lite)](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/)

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю о нем. Даже плагин есть готовый для этого)